# Close form expression for a special case of multinomial distribution

Tags: co.combinatorics

Is there any close form expression for the following multinomial distribution :

$$\sum_{{{0\leq k_1,k_2,\ldots ,k_{m-1}<D}\\k_m=n-(k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_{m-1})}}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_m}a_1^{k_1} a_2^{k_2}\ldots a_m^{k_m}$$

Comment: Apparently, there is no closed-form expression even for the case of $m=2$ (binomial distribution). Bounds/asymptotic is more reasonable to expect here. For $m=2$, see https://publikationen.bibliothek.kit.edu/181894/1821 for example.

Comment: Thanks for the paper. Is there any better bound than $(a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots + a_m)^n$?

Comment: Perhaps, representation $\binom{n}{k_1,\dots,k_m} = \binom{n}{k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}\cdots\binom{n-k_1-\dots-k_{m-1}}{k_m}$ and use of bounds for binomial coefficients can help.

Comment: If the $a_i$ are probabilities you can use the inequality of Mallows, see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2334886